# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: user.first_name

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have received the error message when I try to sign up a new user to my website. Any suggestions as to how I can fix it?: Below is the error message and also the code I have wrote

```html
'sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such column: user.first_name
[SQL: SELECT user.id AS user_id, user.email AS user_email, user.password AS user_password, user.first_name AS user_first_name 
FROM user 
WHERE user.email = ?
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: ('jackt@learningpython.com', 1, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)'
```

```html
@auth.route('/sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method =='POST':
        first_name = request.form.get('firstName')
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        elif len(first_name) < 2:
            flash('First Name must be greater than 1 character.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be atleast 7 characters.', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, first_name=first_name, password=generate_password_hash(password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            flash('Account created!', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
```

```html
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(150))
    notes = db.relationship('Note')
```

Comment: What's your user model look like?

Comment: i have added it to the post now, thanks

Comment: Have you made changes to the user model since you first created the database? Migrations tools like alembic or Flask-Migrate (a wrapper around Alembic) can configure upgrades and migrations for you - but right now it sounds as though you've defined a model without `first_name`, created the database, then added `first_name` to the model without either running db schema updates or else dropping/recreating the database. Check your actual DB tables to see if that column exists because I'm betting it doesn't

Comment: Additionally, anyone that still encounters this problem can just check whether you made any changes to the user model itself or changed or edited the attributes of the database after the database had been created. Just delete the database (the .db file )and run the code again so that a new database can be created with the new changes you made to the database. it helped solve my issue.